# C3js - Mostrar circulo apenas no último ponto do grafico

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Meu gráfico atualmente está com todos os pontos escondidos ( os pontos que me refiro é os círculos "bolinhas"), mas preciso que ele mostre a bolinha somente no último ponto.

Olha essa imagem pra ver exatamente o que eu preciso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poder ver, todos os pontos "Bolinhas" estão escondidas, menos a última.

dei uma olhada no material do C3js, mas não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar com isso.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Meu código atual.

```js
var area_chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#perfor-atual',
            size: { height: 350, width: 800 },
            point: {
                show: false
            },
            color: {
                pattern: ['#000', '#E53935']
            },
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['Meta', 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300],
                    producao,
                ],
                types: {
                    Produção: 'area-spline',
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: ['08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30'],
                    tick: {
                        rotate: 60,
                        multiline: false
                    },
                }
            },
            grid: {
                x: {
                    show: true
                },
                y: {
                    show: true
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container grafico-scroll-personalizada">         
<div class="chart" id="perfor-atual">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9428n6br/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve adicionar esse CSS.

```
#chart .c3-circle:not(:last-child){ display:none; }
```

E depois deve Retirar esse item do JS.

```
point: {
        show: false
       },
```

Seu código vai fica assim.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9428n6br/4/)